# PHP preg_replace keep quotes

Tags: php, preg-replace

I'm terrible with preg_replace and I'm having a tough time figuring out how to add both single and double quotes to the allowed characters. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
$comments = "It's an- "Apple"!?@#$%^&*()=";
$comments = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\s,.!?+-]+', '', $comments);
```

**OutPut:**
Its an- Apple!?

Answer (score 0):

Escape single quote(`\'`) and use the double quote as normally and add the `/` at the end of regex. Although move the hyphen at the end within the [regex character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) or escape within the regex since which has special meaning in [regex character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)(range).

```
$comments = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\s,.!?+\\-"\']+/', '', $comments);
//                                         ---^^^^^---
// or
$comments = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\s,.!?+"\'-]+/', '', $comments);
//                                         --^^^^---
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but for some reason this is removing the entire string and does not return anything.

Comment: @nickyb : can you share the expected input and output, value of `$comments`

Comment: Both still output nothing unfortunately. I have defined $comments and added the output above. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, this expression seems to work `'/[^A-Za-z0-9\s,.!?+\-\'\"]+/'`